# How access map values stored within objects

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm trying create a hashmap and I can't seem to find a way to retrieve an  attribute's value in the map.

I create new key-value pairs by using instance variables in a subclass `Student`.

How can I retrieve all entries that share the same attribute value 'A' when they are created from a subclass?

```
Map<String, Student> students = new HashMap<>();
students.put("0001", new Student("Mike Myers","60 Hey", 'A'));
students.put("0002", new Student("Victor Hughes","21 ddd", 'F'));
students.put("0003", new Student("Elisabeth Carter","56 fff", 'A'));
```

If I do

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Student> entry : students.entrySet())
{
   System.out.println(entry.getValue());
}
```

then I get the values of all attributes (name, address, category). So I wonder how I can get the keys that have the category 'A' only?

Comment: Has the  class `Student` a  method to retrieve category ?

Comment: yes, there is a getCategory that retrieves the object's category under Student subclass

Comment: what is datatype of your `Category`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the value of that attribute as follows:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Student> entry : students.entrySet()) {
    if(entry.getValue().getCategory() == 'A') {
        System.out.println(entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

If you want to create a `Set` of the relevant keys, you can do it as follows:

```
Set<String> keySet = new HashSet<String>();
for (Map.Entry<String, Student> entry : students.entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getValue().getCategory() == 'A') {
        keySet.add(entry.getKey());
    }
}
System.out.println(keySet);
```

Comment: using `==` for comparing `String`s is a bad advice. This is incorrect because “==” only checks the referential equality of two Strings, meaning if they reference the same object or not but not in this case if its the same `category` or not.

Comment: @smithnblack - It's not `String`. Please check again, it's `char`.

Answer (score 1):

With Java 8 this is a nice solution

```
students.values()
    .stream()
    .filter(student -> student.getCategory() == 'A')
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you wanted to print the categories rather than a list of Students you could add the `map` and `foreach` intermediation operation

```
students.values()
    .stream()
    .map(Student::getCategory)
    .filter(cat -> cat == 'A')
    .foreach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: using `==` for comparing `String`s is a bad advice. This is incorrect because “==” only checks the referential equality of two Strings, meaning if they reference the same object or not but not in this case if its the same `category` or not.

Comment: @smithnblack we do not know if `category` is a String or char. If it is char, since it is primitive, it won't have an `equals()` method.

Since OP uses single quotes, I assumed it was a char

Comment: you are right, fixed that downvote ;). Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved as follows:

```
List<String> keys = students.entrySet().stream() //
  .filter(e -> e.getValue().getCategory().equals("A")) //
  .map(e -> e.getKey()) //
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just do it in your `for loop` like this, assuming your `Category` is `String`:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Student> entry : students.entrySet())
{
   if (entry.getCategory().equals("A")) {
     // do something with that entry here
     System.out.println(entry.getValue());
   }
}
```

You need your `getter` `getCategory()` in `Student Class` to work.

Also with Java 8 you can do it with streams like this:

```
List<Student> result = student.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(student -> "A".equals(student.getCategory()))
    .map(x->x.getValue())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
System.out.println(Students.getValues().stream().filter(student -> "A".equalsIgnoreCase(student.getCategory())).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Hope this helps !!!